# Отображение переданных в Ajax-запросе данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для отправки формы используется следующий код:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "/addcomment",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Он отправляет на сервер строку `author=asd&email=asd&comment=adsad`.

Как в обработчике ответа сервера вывести отправленные данные, например, `author`?

Comment: Вы хотите отображать **переданные** данные? Или ответ от сервера?

Comment: Переданные данные

Comment: Тобишь это форма добавления комментариев, будут выводится два вида данных. 1) Нотификатор 2) само обьявление

Comment: Вы зря думаете, что эти подробности проясняют картину

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, эта строка не может **приходить в ответе**!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну вы же сами сохранили `$(this).serialize();` а _serialize_ возвращает строку. Вот она и выводится

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, поймите одну простую вещь: ru.SO это сервис где на конкртные вопросы дают конкретные ответы, а не место для консультирования по всем вашим вопросам!

Comment: @Grundy, я это прекрасно понимаю. А вот ТС почему-то не утруждает себя погружением в тонкости своего вопроса ;)

Comment: @Grundy, вот вы и я знаем, что эта строка, на самом деле не приходит с сервера. А других пользователей ru.SO это поставит в тупик

Comment: Все таки, как получить значение author? :)

Comment: @ОнотолЕ - `console.log(msg.author);`

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, добавьте сюда разметку с формой, и где и как вызываете функцию из поста

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, последний телепат на сайте заминусован внизу. Проясните детально, что вы делаете. Измените тело вопроса. Голоса против вашего вопроса ещё ни о чём вам не говорят?

Comment: @LEQADA, не последний :-)

Comment: echo $_POST['author'], если нужно, чтобы в data пришло то, что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Получение значения элемента формы по его имени:

```js
$('form').on("submit", function() {
    console.log(this.elements["author"].value);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input name="author" />
    <input name="email" />
    <input name="comment" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: но куда вы дели ajax запрос?

Comment: @Grundy так он не имеет отношения к вопросу, по сути.

Comment: ну вообще говоря - в посте именно в колбэке его получение этого значения ожидается

Comment: @Grundy вроде как давно устаканилсь на том, что автору нужны данные из самой формы, но `.serialize()` возвращает строку, из которой вытащить `author` достаточно проблематично. Я предложил вариант получения `author`.

Comment: ну так можно же вытаскивать из самой формы, не использую сериализованное значение

Comment: @Grundy согласен, переборщил. Сейчас перепишу.

Comment: @Alex скажем так: автор пытался прояснить свой вопрос. И в комментариях, и в правке. Думаю, на волне негатива он просто плюнул на это и ушел. Да, качественным изложение вопроса не назвать, но всё же вопрос понятен.

Comment: @Alex да были там относительно резкие и негативные фразы. Понятно, что тут не детский сад, и носить автора на руках, равно как и делать всё за него, включая формулирование вопроса, не планируется. Собственно, ответ я свой дал только после того, как более-менее убедился в том, что понимаю, что нужно автору. Всегда есть шанс, что автор имел в виду что-то другое, причем в некоторых вопросах этот шанс больше, но всё же. Формулировка вопроса в последней реакции выглядит достаточно понятной.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, лучше поступить так:

```
var data = x.serializeArray().reduce(function (res, cur) {
  res[cur.name] = cur.value;
  return res;
}, {});

$.ajax({
    url: "/addcomment",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(data.author);
    }
});
```

---

Дополнительно, как распарсить отправляемую строку:

```
var data = "author=asd&email=asd&comment=adsad";
var author = decodeURIComponent((data.match(/(?:^|&)author=([^&]*)(?:&|$)/)||['',''])[1]);
alert(author);
```

Comment: Сериализовать форму а потом парсить полученную строку... сильно

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в моём ответе нет сериализации, только парсинг. А с нормальным получением есть ответ Regent рядом, которому я уже поставил плюсик.

Comment: Вопрос же как распарсить строку, а не как получить значение.

Comment: Вы попались на телепатии. Вопрос: "_Как получить ... данные_". Ни слова о парсинге в нем нет

Comment: А еще можете посмотреть на оригинальный вопрос, до правок ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, с этого надо было начать. Поправил вопрос, дописал ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня [первоначальная версия](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/469829/revisions) ответа тоже была на основе `.serializeArray()` :) А потом я понял, что меня просто унесло не в ту сторону на фоне много раз повторяющегося `serialize` в этом вопросе и в самом первом ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Получить переменную:

```
$author = $_POST['author'];
```

Comment: @Grundy, я ж говорил ;)

Comment: А откуда взялся в вопросе _PHP_, да ещё и на клиентской стороне, в браузере?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да кто ж знал-то :-D

Comment: @Rikaz хорошо, стоило уточнить, что я спрашивал про данный конкретный вопрос, где нет ни слова как в метках, так и в тексте и комментариях, про _PHP_.

Comment: @Rikaz, а он его в браузере запускал? или все-таки на сервере?

Comment: @Grundy, ну наверное на сервере.

Comment: @Regent, моя эрудиция позволила предположить, что ajax-запрос передается на сервер

Comment: @Rikaz а почему вы думаете, что там PHP(хотя в вопросе про другое судя по всему)?

Comment: @Rikaz ... где его, например, с удовольствием примут _Tomcat_ и сервлет, написанный на _Java_. Но проблема даже не в том, что вы пытаетесь угадать язык, на котором написан сервер. Проблема в том, что автору вопроса данные нужные на клиентской стороне.

Comment: @Vartlok, я телепат

Comment: @Rikaz, как-то не очень, если честно :-)

Comment: Почему вместо того, чтоб попытаться помочь автору, вы ищете к чему придраться?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
var author = $(this).find("[name='author']").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "/addcomment",
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: function(msg) {
      console.log(author);
  }
});
```

Comment: Достойный ответ. Однако, если каждый раз поощрять людей, которые даже не могут нормально сформулировать проблему сообщество скоро захлебнется в таких вопросах.

Comment: Понял Ваш сарказм. Рад, что Вы почувствовали мой. Удалю.

Comment: Но я ведь серьезно: ответ действительно хороший)))